# Using Multi Monitor on X.Org Server - Noveau display driver doesn't work properly

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, xorg, 23.04

I'm trying to use Xorg drivers because they consume less of my laptop battery but i also use a second monitor connected via a DVI cable which works fine when using proprietary NVIDIA Drivers but only half of the second monitor is rendered and half pink screened when using the open source Xorg drivers. My Laptop info if helps,

ASUS TUF FX505DT
NVIDIA Geforce gtx 1650 Mobile/MaxQ
AMD Ryzen 355H
AMD integrated GPU
Ubuntu 23.04

Please someone help me out!
Thanks in advance ! cheers ! :>